# DateTime's functions in PowerShell

Tags: datetime, powershell

I write an application in PowerShell, and I want to convert seconds to date.

In C# there is an AddSeconds function that adds seconds to date. What function in PowerShell does a similar performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since the .NET framework is right at your fingertips, you can do

```
$d1 = [System.DateTime]::Now
```

And then

```
$d2 = $d1.AddSeconds(30)
```

Get-Date then appears to be a wrapper to the DateTime object and the following would work well:

```
$d3 = Get-Date 23.10.2010 -Format dd.MM.yyyy
```

Comment: if I want to write instead Now another date time, what format should be written? thanks

Comment: Use Parse() or Get-Date -Format. See Get-Help Get-Date for more information. They use DateTimeFormatInfo Class. Do check out MSDN documentation on that

Answer (score 2):

```
PS C:\> $date = Get-Date

PS C:\> $date.AddSeconds(10)

Monday, November 15, 2010 6:24:31 PM
```